# Flutter:PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null))

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with my flutter app. When I run and use the login feature, it display: PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)). The flow: Sign in Button -> login_controller -> AuthenticationRepository.

[Click here for the error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMJuY.png)

```
/// Sign in button
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => controller.emailAndPasswordSignIn(),
                  child: const Text(TTexts.signIn),
                ),
              ),
```

It will use the logic here, and the problem is at the `AuthenticationRepository` class as shown in the picture (click on the hyperlink). I also have some custom class but I don't think it will be helpful here. The comment inside the code I think it will be enough. I also have try the flutter clean and flutter pub get but still not working. All the package is up-to-date.

```
  /// -- Email and Password SignIn
  Future<void> emailAndPasswordSignIn() async {
    try {
      // Start Loading
      TFullScreenLoader.openLoadingDialog(
          'Logging you in...', TImages.docerAnimation);

      // Check Internet Connectivity
      final isConnected = await NetworkManager.instance.isConnected();
      if (!isConnected) {
        TFullScreenLoader.stopLoading();
        return;
      }

      // Form Validation
      if (!loginFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        TFullScreenLoader.stopLoading();
        return;
      }

      // Save Data if Remember Me is Selected
      if (rememberMe.value) {
        localStorage.write('REMEMBER_ME_EMAIL', email.text.trim());
        localStorage.write('REMEMBER_ME_PASSWORD', password.text.trim());
      }

      // Login user using Email & Password Authentication
      final userCredentials = await AuthenticationRepository.instance
          .loginWithEmailAndPassword(email.text.trim(), password.text.trim());

      // Save user record
      await userController.saveUserRecord(userCredentials);

      // Remove Loader
      TFullScreenLoader.stopLoading();

      // Redirect
      AuthenticationRepository.instance.screenRedirect();
    } catch (e) {
      TFullScreenLoader.stopLoading();
      TLoaders.errorSnackBar(title: 'Oh Snap!', message: e.toString());
    }
  }
```

```
  class AuthenticationRepository extends GetxController {
  static AuthenticationRepository get instance => Get.find();

  /// Variables
  final deviceStorage = GetStorage();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  /// Get Authenticated User Data
  User? get authUser => _auth.currentUser;

  /// Called from main.dart on app laucnh
  @override
  void onReady() {
    FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
    screenRedirect();
  }

  /// Function to Show Relevant Screen
  void screenRedirect() async {
    final user = _auth.currentUser;

    if (user != null) {
      if (user.emailVerified) {
        Get.offAll(() => const NavigationMenu());
      } else {
        Get.offAll(() => VerifyEmailScreen(
              email: _auth.currentUser?.email,
            ));
      }
    } else {
      // Local Storage
      deviceStorage.writeIfNull('isFirstTime', true);

      // Check if it's the first time launching the app
      deviceStorage.read('isFirstTime') != true
          ? Get.offAll(() => const LoginScreen())
          : Get.offAll(const OnBoardingScreen());
    }
  }

  /* ---------- Email & Password sign-in -----------------*/

  /// [EmailAuthenctication] - SignIn
  Future<UserCredential> loginWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password); // this where the exception error happen
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      throw TFirebaseAuthException(e.code).message;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw TFirebaseException(e.code).message;
    } on FormatException catch (_) {
      throw const TFormatException();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      throw TPlatformException(e.code).message;
    } catch (e) {
      throw 'Something went wrong. Please try again';
    }
  }
}
```

This is my first time doing a complex flutter project and quite newbie on backend/logic programming. Any help/discussion is welcome

Comment: Update: I have solved the issue. I tried without running and debugging which mean open the application on the emulator instead of run it on the visual studio code and it work while not displaying the above error.

Answer (score 0):

```
!loginFormKey.currentState!
```

This line causing that error

You can assign it like this way.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it says currentState is null. Still stuck here

Comment: you can check the answer, made an update

Comment: I see sorry to not inform you earlier but I already have a class that contain form widget. But with your updated answer I understand that it will give an error if there is no form widget. I have solved the issue. I tried without running and debugging and it work while not displaying the above error. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

make sure the loginFormKey has been assigned to a Form widget, I think you missed it and the error says currentState is null.

Comment: How to assign it to a Form widget?

Comment: Wrap your view (for example the column that you have used to set the textFields inside it) with a Form widget and assign the key.

Comment: I see sorry to not inform you earlier but I already have a class that contain form widget. But your explanation does make me more understand in flutter development. The issue here is the emulator. I tried without running and debugging and it work while not displaying the above error. Thanks again!